# Contour integral of $\sqrt[3]{z^3-1}$ on $|z| = 2$ and branches

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

This is an exam question that i'm trying to figure out.

Apart from the title, there is a note added to the question that says that:
The branch of $\sqrt[3]{}$ is the one that has $\sqrt[3]{7} \in \mathbb{R}$

For the integral I tried using the Residue at infinity using the usual substitution. I get that $$g(w) = \frac{1}{w^3}\sqrt[3]{1-w^3}$$ is analytic in $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ except at zero where $w=0$ is an order $3$ pole. So the residue at zero is: $$res_0(g) = \frac{(\sqrt[3]{1-w^3})''(0)}{2!} = 0$$ Therefore the integral equals $0$.

Although all the above, I feel something is wrong cause I did not use the information about the branch at all, and frankly I have no idea how to use it. I know that there are three branch points, namely: $1, e^{\frac{2}{3}i\pi},e^{-\frac{2}{3}i\pi}$ so I guess a branch cut will have to be two rays coming out of $1$ and passing through the other two?

But still I fail to see how the fact that the branch has to be one so that $\sqrt[3]{7} \in \mathbb{R}$ helps me here, is it possible to have a branch where it isn't so? Perhaps I still don't really understand branches as well as I thought I did.

Any thoughts or input on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To answer one question: you can get a different branch (one that doesn't satisfy $\sqrt[3]7\in\Bbb R$) by multplying the whole function by a cube root of unity. That will multiply the answer by the same constant—but since the answer is $0$, this choice of branch didn't matter. Really, when you look at the substitute function $g(w)$, you're only using information about that function for $|w| \le \frac12$, so the branches never come into play.

Comment: I agree with your instinct to understand branch cuts as well as possible, though. For example, you proposed a branch cut shaped like an angle with vertex at $1$. What if you used instead a branch cut shaped like an angle with vertex at $e^{2\pi i/3}$: which values of $\sqrt[3]{z^3-1}$ would be (un)affected? What if you used a branch cut consisting of three line segments connecting the three cube roots of unity to $0$?

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin, I see your point. If I take for example the 2nd branch cut you suggested, the entire imaginary axis is unaffected by the cut, while the cut I suggested does affect it. Also I noticed that if $z=2$ then $\sqrt[3]{z^3-1} = \sqrt[3]{7}$ so I guess the note about the branch satisfying $\sqrt[3]{7}$ means that the branch cut is not cutting the entire positive real axis starting from $z=1$.